# How to use ExtJS FormPanel with JSF 2.0

Tags: extjs, jsf-2, viewstate, myfaces

Im trying to use ExtJS FormPanel with JSF 2.0 + MyFaces 2.0.4. ExtJS is a great JavaScript framework at all. But it doesnt use DOM of Page. So the main problem starts with here. To put JSF beans in work i must put h:form tag inside the XHTML(or handle viewstate) since it must synchronize with ViewState.

But ExtJS doesnt aware of THE ViewState. How can i make ExtJS aware of THE ViewState and synchronize at all. I wish to put it in FormPanel....items:[{.....}]. But couldnt find any way.

And one more thing; There may be two or more form on a single page. If i cant put it in ExtJS items[{...}] how can i do each forms management.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've used both of these frameworks pretty extensively, and I think you're barking up the wrong tree here. By the time you figure out how to couple these into the JSF lifecycle, I think you could have written the REST resources on your server with that Ext could consume.

Or if you are sticking with JSF, you could try Primefaces or one of the many other JSF component libraries if you're looking for some snazzy data grids. They aren't as nice as Extjs, but if you are a JSF shop it is worth looking into.

There's also Ext GWT, which has nothing to do with JSF of course, but I've never used that.